# How to delete all rows from a group, if a different column meets condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and then a calculation to identify outliers:

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DF
d = { 
    'Day': ['M','M','M','T','T','T','W','W','W','W','W','W','W','F','F','F','F'],
    'Criteria':[30,35,2.5,3,6,15,20,1.5,4,25,50,75,2,4,9,2,36]  
    }           
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
#Outliers calc
lower_limit = df.Criteria.quantile(.05)
upper_limit = df.Criteria.quantile(.95)
df['Flag'] = df.Criteria.between(lower_limit, upper_limit)

df
```

[image]

You can see that the `Day` `W` contails an outlier (2 in this case).

Essentially if a `Flag` equals `False` I would like to drop all rows from that `Day` group.

So my expected result is all `'W'` Days are removed from the table. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [do not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of your dataframes, the code-formatted result of [`print(df)`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for example is much more useful (though here you have the code creating the dataframe in the question so it’s not too bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html): retains those groups of `Day`s that have their `Flag`s `all` True:

```
>>> df.groupby("Day").filter(lambda d: d.Flag.all())

   Day  Criteria  Flag
0    M      30.0  True
1    M      35.0  True
2    M       2.5  True
3    T       3.0  True
4    T       6.0  True
5    T      15.0  True
13   F       4.0  True
14   F       9.0  True
15   F       2.0  True
16   F      36.0  True
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you want :

```
import numpy as np

df = df[df.groupby('Day').Flag.transform(np.all)]
df
```

Comment: Thanks alot! i saw the other answer first and it work which is why i accepted that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this should be fast than `filter`

```
out = df[~df.Day.isin(df.loc[~df.Flag,'Day'])]
Out[20]: 
   Day  Criteria  Flag
0    M      30.0  True
1    M      35.0  True
2    M       2.5  True
3    T       3.0  True
4    T       6.0  True
5    T      15.0  True
13   F       4.0  True
14   F       9.0  True
15   F       2.0  True
16   F      36.0  True
```